# Mongoose subdocuments sort

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

This is actually two questions.

Using MongooseJS

1. Can you set the default sort order for a Schema?
2. can you control how subdocuments are sorted?

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer. I can google around and maybe look in the code, but maybe if you explain what you're trying to accomplish, someone can provide another method.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [options available for Schema creation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema) it looks like this is not an available option:

```
autoIndex: bool - defaults to true
bufferCommands: bool - defaults to
true capped: bool - defaults to false
collection: string - no default
id: bool - defaults to true
_id: bool - defaults to true
minimize: bool - controls document#toObject behavior when called manually - defaults to true
read: string
safe: bool - defaults to true.
shardKey: bool - defaults
to null strict: bool - defaults to true toJSON - object - no default
toObject - object - no default
versionKey: bool - defaults to "__v"
```

You may be able to make a [plugin](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html) that accomplishes what you're trying to do though.